# ROR SESSION STORE: Session store with :redis_store not getting cookie with session_id in it in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, session-cookies, session-store, redis-rails

### session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store,
                                       servers: ["redis://localhost:6379/0/session"],
                                       expire_after: 90.minutes,
                                       key: "key",
                                       threadsafe: true,
                                       secure: true
```

middleware used :-

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::RedisStore
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
```

when i try to insert key, value in session object it successfully get inserted and even i can see in redis db the session get created succesfully
as per my knowledge `ActionDispatch::Session::RedisStore` automatically generates cookie with `_session_id` key in it which is used to retrieve session data from redis but in my case i am not receiving any cookie in response
please help am i missing something?

tried many other gems like redis-actionpack, redis-session-store etc none worked

Comment: How do you know you're not receiving a cookie. Show us the evidence you used to arrive at that conclusion.